# Layouting inside DockPanel

Tags: wpf-controls

Hi there I am trying to layout may App in dockpanel.
I have on relatively wider Grid on left and narrow Grid on right. I want the right grid of fixed width but left one to grow as I resize my main window. Here is my XAML:

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="WebSpark.MainWindow"
x:Name="Window"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="640" Height="480">

<DockPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FF474747" LastChildFill="True">
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="23" Background="#FFEF1212"  />
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="23" Background="#FFF7E30D"  />
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="#FF0A38F1" MinHeight="396" Width="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot,Path=ActualWidth}" MaxWidth="428"  />
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="198" />
</DockPanel>
```

Here is the behavior. Restored window: http://s17.postimage.org/tk1pov6b3/Restored.png
Maximized window: http://s9.postimage.org/457s5r23j/Maximized.png

As you can see in the maximized window, the blue panel should have stretched, but it is not. What's wrong here? Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of LastChildFill="True". This code ensures that the grey box has fixed size and the blue one has a variable size.

```
<DockPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FF474747" LastChildFill="True">
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="23" Background="#FFEF1212"  />
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="23" Background="#FFF7E30D"  />
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="198" />
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="#FF0A38F1" MinHeight="396" />
</DockPanel>
```